# WebSocket4Net System.InvalidOperationException: No operation in progress

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, websocket4net

I'm creating an Android App using Xamarin.Android this app comunicate to a WebSocket Server (using WebSocket4Net Module) for authenticate users and other Tasks,But when i open the connection whith ws.Open(); during the Debug 
breaks out an UnHandled Exception : **System.InvalidOperationException: No operation in progress** Here is the complete code:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Threading;
using WebSocket4Net;

namespace App36
{
public  static class socket
{
   public static WebSocket ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.157:8081/");

    public static void start()
    {
        ws.Open();
    }
}
}
```

Someone Knows where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Helio, I don't know if you get the answer about this. But maybe this solve your problem. https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41616

Regards.